# Custom module update with project status url

Tags: updating

My .info file is the following.

```
name = {some_name}
description = This will contain all {some_name} related information
package = {Package_name}
core = 7.x

; Information added by Drupal.org packaging script on 2014-10-03
version = "7.x-1.1"
core = "7.x"
project = "{project_name}"
project status url=http://domain.com/{project_name}/7.0/sub_module
datestamp = "1432104957"
```

I uploaded the sub_module.zip and the sub_module.tar.gz files, as well as the sub_module folder to the above project status URL, with .info version set to 7.x.2.1.

Still I'm not getting any updates for my custom module.
Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

The project status URL you provided in the .info file is wrong: It should be http://domain.com, in the same way for Drupal.org that URL is http://updates.drupal.org/. A Drupal site will then access (in your case) `http://domain.com/{project_name}/{drupal_version}` to verify the module needs to be updated.
`http://domain.com/{project_name}/{drupal_version}` needs to return XML data listing all the versions available for that project and that Drupal version.

To make an example with a project hosted on Drupal.org, the list of all the versions available for Drupal 7.x of the Views module is returned from http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/views/7.x, which returns the following XML data.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
<title>Views</title>
<short_name>views</short_name>
<dc:creator>merlinofchaos</dc:creator>
<type>project_module</type>
<api_version>7.x</api_version>
<recommended_major>3</recommended_major>
<supported_majors>3</supported_majors>
<default_major>3</default_major>
<project_status>published</project_status>
<link>https://www.drupal.org/project/views</link>
<terms><term><name>Projects</name><value>Modules</value></term><term><name>Maintenance status</name><value>Seeking co-maintainer(s)</value></term><term><name>Development status</name><value>Under active development</value></term></terms>
<releases>
<release><name>views 7.x-3.16</name><version>7.x-3.16</version><tag>7.x-3.16</tag><version_major>3</version_major><version_patch>16</version_patch><status>published</status><release_link>https://www.drupal.org/project/views/releases/7.x-3.16</release_link><download_link>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.16.tar.gz</download_link><date>1491158584</date><mdhash>d840cb148809da844b93d73b16b453f9</mdhash><filesize>1643030</filesize><files><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.16.tar.gz</url><archive_type>tar.gz</archive_type><md5>d840cb148809da844b93d73b16b453f9</md5><size>1643030</size><filedate>1491158584</filedate></file><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.16.zip</url><archive_type>zip</archive_type><md5>58da4a76b03278e613f8298e69f761c6</md5><size>1913513</size><filedate>1491158584</filedate></file></files><terms><term><name>Release type</name><value>Bug fixes</value></term></terms><security covered="1"/></release><release><name>views 7.x-3.16-rc1</name><version>7.x-3.16-rc1</version><tag>7.x-3.16-rc1</tag><version_major>3</version_major><version_patch>16</version_patch><version_extra>rc1</version_extra><status>published</status><release_link>https://www.drupal.org/project/views/releases/7.x-3.16-rc1</release_link><download_link>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.16-rc1.tar.gz</download_link><date>1489763584</date><mdhash>cba59381dbf64ac9d9d76fa549b4c7c1</mdhash><filesize>1642814</filesize><files><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.16-rc1.tar.gz</url><archive_type>tar.gz</archive_type><md5>cba59381dbf64ac9d9d76fa549b4c7c1</md5><size>1642814</size><filedate>1489763584</filedate></file><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.16-rc1.zip</url><archive_type>zip</archive_type><md5>460ed4581a0a7680fad79e1c124cedc3</md5><size>1913275</size><filedate>1489763584</filedate></file></files><terms><term><name>Release type</name><value>Bug fixes</value></term></terms><security>RC releases are not covered by Drupal security advisories.</security></release><release><name>views 7.x-3.15</name><version>7.x-3.15</version><tag>7.x-3.15</tag><version_major>3</version_major><version_patch>15</version_patch><status>published</status><release_link>https://www.drupal.org/project/views/releases/7.x-3.15</release_link><download_link>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.15.tar.gz</download_link><date>1487784184</date><mdhash>473cb5384456d55af988feabc1af12ed</mdhash><filesize>1642425</filesize><files><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.15.tar.gz</url><archive_type>tar.gz</archive_type><md5>473cb5384456d55af988feabc1af12ed</md5><size>1642425</size><filedate>1487784184</filedate></file><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.15.zip</url><archive_type>zip</archive_type><md5>d22aa50667d4905a6b954c58d7c29832</md5><size>1913348</size><filedate>1487784184</filedate></file></files><terms><term><name>Release type</name><value>Security update</value></term><term><name>Release type</name><value>Bug fixes</value></term></terms><security covered="1"/></release><release><name>views 7.x-3.14</name><version>7.x-3.14</version><tag>7.x-3.14</tag><version_major>3</version_major><version_patch>14</version_patch><status>published</status><release_link>https://www.drupal.org/project/views/releases/7.x-3.14</release_link><download_link>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.14.tar.gz</download_link><date>1466019539</date><mdhash>168bb684c8f34297be94b03c797841e5</mdhash><filesize>1656594</filesize><files><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.14.tar.gz</url><archive_type>tar.gz</archive_type><md5>168bb684c8f34297be94b03c797841e5</md5><size>1656594</size><filedate>1466019539</filedate></file><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.14.zip</url><archive_type>zip</archive_type><md5>b8ee0f4278b2f67e4d10997dc2a05ec4</md5><size>1913123</size><filedate>1466019539</filedate></file></files><terms><term><name>Release type</name><value>Security update</value></term><term><name>Release type</name><value>Bug fixes</value></term></terms><security covered="1"/></release><release><name>views 7.x-3.13</name><version>7.x-3.13</version><tag>7.x-3.13</tag><version_major>3</version_major><version_patch>13</version_patch><status>published</status><release_link>https://www.drupal.org/project/views/releases/7.x-3.13</release_link><download_link>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.13.tar.gz</download_link><date>1446804839</date><mdhash>50d3b231f689f8c4ff15d79ea3c261d9</mdhash><filesize>1650157</filesize><files><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.13.tar.gz</url><archive_type>tar.gz</archive_type><md5>50d3b231f689f8c4ff15d79ea3c261d9</md5><size>1650157</size><filedate>1446804839</filedate></file><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.13.zip</url><archive_type>zip</archive_type><md5>d30756ba6b3489fd919ddd359f5decad</md5><size>1900939</size><filedate>1446804839</filedate></file></files><terms><term><name>Release type</name><value>Bug fixes</value></term></terms><security covered="1"/></release><release><name>views 7.x-3.12</name><version>7.x-3.12</version><tag>7.x-3.12</tag><version_major>3</version_major><version_patch>12</version_patch><status>published</status><release_link>https://www.drupal.org/project/views/releases/7.x-3.12</release_link><download_link>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.12.tar.gz</download_link><date>1446653339</date><mdhash>a50033bb090730176d9263ddae7f32b2</mdhash><filesize>1650130</filesize><files><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.12.tar.gz</url><archive_type>tar.gz</archive_type><md5>a50033bb090730176d9263ddae7f32b2</md5><size>1650130</size><filedate>1446653339</filedate></file><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.12.zip</url><archive_type>zip</archive_type><md5>56beb9d18dcc252ca77834f52b9050d1</md5><size>1900868</size><filedate>1446653339</filedate></file></files><terms><term><name>Release type</name><value>Bug fixes</value></term></terms><security covered="1"/></release><release><name>views 7.x-3.11</name><version>7.x-3.11</version><tag>7.x-3.11</tag><version_major>3</version_major><version_patch>11</version_patch><status>published</status><release_link>https://www.drupal.org/project/views/releases/7.x-3.11</release_link><download_link>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.11.tar.gz</download_link><date>1430320981</date><mdhash>00d722e1d8ed57e912c8bd586cf2edbe</mdhash><filesize>1649389</filesize><files><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.11.tar.gz</url><archive_type>tar.gz</archive_type><md5>00d722e1d8ed57e912c8bd586cf2edbe</md5><size>1649389</size><filedate>1430320981</filedate></file><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.11.zip</url><archive_type>zip</archive_type><md5>448b10631be9423948f4bad59d269593</md5><size>1899261</size><filedate>1430320981</filedate></file></files><terms><term><name>Release type</name><value>Security update</value></term><term><name>Release type</name><value>Bug fixes</value></term></terms><security covered="1"/></release><release><name>views 7.x-3.10</name><version>7.x-3.10</version><tag>7.x-3.10</tag><version_major>3</version_major><version_patch>10</version_patch><status>published</status><release_link>https://www.drupal.org/project/views/releases/7.x-3.10</release_link><download_link>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.10.tar.gz</download_link><date>1423648081</date><mdhash>c9806ffd69448bc505a67e790f97da58</mdhash><filesize>1648314</filesize><files><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.10.tar.gz</url><archive_type>tar.gz</archive_type><md5>c9806ffd69448bc505a67e790f97da58</md5><size>1648314</size><filedate>1423648081</filedate></file><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.10.zip</url><archive_type>zip</archive_type><md5>45246351588a7f9f74a7d8ba1e0554f4</md5><size>1897924</size><filedate>1423648081</filedate></file></files><terms><term><name>Release type</name><value>Security update</value></term><term><name>Release type</name><value>Bug fixes</value></term></terms><security covered="1"/></release><release><name>views 7.x-3.8</name><version>7.x-3.8</version><tag>7.x-3.8</tag><version_major>3</version_major><version_patch>8</version_patch><status>published</status><release_link>https://www.drupal.org/project/views/releases/7.x-3.8</release_link><download_link>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.8.tar.gz</download_link><date>1400618927</date><mdhash>0fbe71c455f5d34c7193797563b63b3f</mdhash><filesize>1646817</filesize><files><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.8.tar.gz</url><archive_type>tar.gz</archive_type><md5>0fbe71c455f5d34c7193797563b63b3f</md5><size>1646817</size><filedate>1400618927</filedate></file><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.8.zip</url><archive_type>zip</archive_type><md5>c1a997653b21943a86bcd42f5c803403</md5><size>1886165</size><filedate>1400618927</filedate></file></files><terms><term><name>Release type</name><value>Security update</value></term><term><name>Release type</name><value>Bug fixes</value></term><term><name>Release type</name><value>New features</value></term></terms><security covered="1"/></release><release><name>views 7.x-3.7</name><version>7.x-3.7</version><tag>7.x-3.7</tag><version_major>3</version_major><version_patch>7</version_patch><status>published</status><release_link>https://www.drupal.org/project/views/releases/7.x-3.7</release_link><download_link>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.7.tar.gz</download_link><date>1365499237</date><mdhash>3f36f0d13f3b724d719f6729cbc110ba</mdhash><filesize>1639539</filesize><files><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.7.tar.gz</url><archive_type>tar.gz</archive_type><md5>3f36f0d13f3b724d719f6729cbc110ba</md5><size>1639539</size><filedate>1365499237</filedate></file><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.7.zip</url><archive_type>zip</archive_type><md5>c764bcc139e3698b24f4bfcc531542e4</md5><size>1878608</size><filedate>1365499237</filedate></file></files><terms><term><name>Release type</name><value>Bug fixes</value></term></terms><security covered="1"/></release><release><name>views 7.x-3.6</name><version>7.x-3.6</version><tag>7.x-3.6</tag><version_major>3</version_major><version_patch>6</version_patch><status>published</status><release_link>https://www.drupal.org/project/views/releases/7.x-3.6</release_link><download_link>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.6.tar.gz</download_link><date>1363810217</date><mdhash>1531a1ece3970332db1559b854f5dcc9</mdhash><filesize>1639219</filesize><files><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.6.tar.gz</url><archive_type>tar.gz</archive_type><md5>1531a1ece3970332db1559b854f5dcc9</md5><size>1639219</size><filedate>1363810217</filedate></file><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.6.zip</url><archive_type>zip</archive_type><md5>0d7c7de301caa52670869060e22d1ef3</md5><size>1878465</size><filedate>1363810217</filedate></file></files><terms><term><name>Release type</name><value>Security update</value></term></terms><security covered="1"/></release><release><name>views 7.x-3.5</name><version>7.x-3.5</version><tag>7.x-3.5</tag><version_major>3</version_major><version_patch>5</version_patch><status>published</status><release_link>https://www.drupal.org/project/views/releases/7.x-3.5</release_link><download_link>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.5.tar.gz</download_link><date>1345829395</date><mdhash>fba70998d4ebcca5116ef5ee90117738</mdhash><filesize>1632919</filesize><files><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.5.tar.gz</url><archive_type>tar.gz</archive_type><md5>fba70998d4ebcca5116ef5ee90117738</md5><size>1632919</size><filedate>1345829395</filedate></file><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.5.zip</url><archive_type>zip</archive_type><md5>8b1102f6cd54949eee147c63c4fd352b</md5><size>1866348</size><filedate>1345829395</filedate></file></files><terms><term><name>Release type</name><value>Bug fixes</value></term></terms><security covered="1"/></release><release><name>views 7.x-3.4</name><version>7.x-3.4</version><tag>7.x-3.4</tag><version_major>3</version_major><version_patch>4</version_patch><status>published</status><release_link>https://www.drupal.org/project/views/releases/7.x-3.4</release_link><download_link>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.4.tar.gz</download_link><date>1345559303</date><mdhash>72bd0f35ac467aed74e533c10a76c93f</mdhash><filesize>1632803</filesize><files><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.4.tar.gz</url><archive_type>tar.gz</archive_type><md5>72bd0f35ac467aed74e533c10a76c93f</md5><size>1632803</size><filedate>1345559303</filedate></file><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.4.zip</url><archive_type>zip</archive_type><md5>0e92dc862bea87904d507af72e710af7</md5><size>1866193</size><filedate>1345559303</filedate></file></files><terms><term><name>Release type</name><value>New features</value></term><term><name>Release type</name><value>Bug fixes</value></term></terms><security covered="1"/></release><release><name>views 7.x-3.3</name><version>7.x-3.3</version><tag>7.x-3.3</tag><version_major>3</version_major><version_patch>3</version_patch><status>published</status><release_link>https://www.drupal.org/project/views/releases/7.x-3.3</release_link><download_link>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.3.tar.gz</download_link><date>1329946249</date><mdhash>70f24086dc7acfa7fc23c6148c7f8e00</mdhash><filesize>1583249</filesize><files><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.3.tar.gz</url><archive_type>tar.gz</archive_type><md5>70f24086dc7acfa7fc23c6148c7f8e00</md5><size>1583249</size><filedate>1329946249</filedate></file><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.3.zip</url><archive_type>zip</archive_type><md5>e8b5f8d4de7526d2919993bb3a34c0bf</md5><size>1803054</size><filedate>1329946249</filedate></file></files><terms><term><name>Release type</name><value>Bug fixes</value></term></terms><security covered="1"/></release><release><name>views 7.x-3.2</name><version>7.x-3.2</version><tag>7.x-3.2</tag><version_major>3</version_major><version_patch>2</version_patch><status>published</status><release_link>https://www.drupal.org/project/views/releases/7.x-3.2</release_link><download_link>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.2.tar.gz</download_link><date>1329778551</date><mdhash>c350603991445ca69b30eddf3befe887</mdhash><filesize>1582617</filesize><files><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.2.tar.gz</url><archive_type>tar.gz</archive_type><md5>c350603991445ca69b30eddf3befe887</md5><size>1582617</size><filedate>1329778551</filedate></file><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.2.zip</url><archive_type>zip</archive_type><md5>641a7c36bc39d5c17b997ff5babf6d47</md5><size>1801836</size><filedate>1329778552</filedate></file></files><terms><term><name>Release type</name><value>Bug fixes</value></term></terms><security covered="1"/></release><release><name>views 7.x-3.1</name><version>7.x-3.1</version><tag>7.x-3.1</tag><version_major>3</version_major><version_patch>1</version_patch><status>published</status><release_link>https://www.drupal.org/project/views/releases/7.x-3.1</release_link><download_link>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.1.tar.gz</download_link><date>1326750948</date><mdhash>e158435dc66d1d89a0df587c39ef1a23</mdhash><filesize>1575585</filesize><files><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.1.tar.gz</url><archive_type>tar.gz</archive_type><md5>e158435dc66d1d89a0df587c39ef1a23</md5><size>1575585</size><filedate>1326750948</filedate></file><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.1.zip</url><archive_type>zip</archive_type><md5>43999fc1888c1aa88f1d20288aace84c</md5><size>1792932</size><filedate>1326750949</filedate></file></files><terms><term><name>Release type</name><value>Bug fixes</value></term></terms><security covered="1"/></release><release><name>views 7.x-3.0</name><version>7.x-3.0</version><tag>7.x-3.0</tag><version_major>3</version_major><version_patch>0</version_patch><status>published</status><release_link>https://www.drupal.org/project/views/releases/7.x-3.0</release_link><download_link>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.0.tar.gz</download_link><date>1324170451</date><mdhash>1be8cbd6fd3f37bfd1493693dfa95d8d</mdhash><filesize>1461460</filesize><files><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.0.tar.gz</url><archive_type>tar.gz</archive_type><md5>1be8cbd6fd3f37bfd1493693dfa95d8d</md5><size>1461460</size><filedate>1324170451</filedate></file><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.0.zip</url><archive_type>zip</archive_type><md5>99769e8808519ae36171fa619cf00997</md5><size>1672723</size><filedate>1324170451</filedate></file></files><terms><term><name>Release type</name><value>Bug fixes</value></term></terms><security covered="1"/></release><release><name>views 7.x-3.0-rc3</name><version>7.x-3.0-rc3</version><tag>7.x-3.0-rc3</tag><version_major>3</version_major><version_patch>0</version_patch><version_extra>rc3</version_extra><status>published</status><release_link>https://www.drupal.org/project/views/releases/7.x-3.0-rc3</release_link><download_link>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.0-rc3.tar.gz</download_link><date>1321467945</date><mdhash>b3e58f4195308e37621155d3c843e53f</mdhash><filesize>1456218</filesize><files><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.0-rc3.tar.gz</url><archive_type>tar.gz</archive_type><md5>b3e58f4195308e37621155d3c843e53f</md5><size>1456218</size><filedate>1321467945</filedate></file><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.0-rc3.zip</url><archive_type>zip</archive_type><md5>502f84cfadb4bf4744b6c452fc01f2d6</md5><size>1665759</size><filedate>1321467946</filedate></file></files><terms><term><name>Release type</name><value>Security update</value></term><term><name>Release type</name><value>Bug fixes</value></term></terms><security>RC releases are not covered by Drupal security advisories.</security></release><release><name>views 7.x-3.0-rc1</name><version>7.x-3.0-rc1</version><tag>7.x-3.0-rc1</tag><version_major>3</version_major><version_patch>0</version_patch><version_extra>rc1</version_extra><status>published</status><release_link>https://www.drupal.org/project/views/releases/7.x-3.0-rc1</release_link><download_link>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.0-rc1.tar.gz</download_link><date>1308341221</date><mdhash>e158db78ae2f8cc615edb910a09384b0</mdhash><filesize>1481151</filesize><files><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.0-rc1.tar.gz</url><archive_type>tar.gz</archive_type><md5>e158db78ae2f8cc615edb910a09384b0</md5><size>1481151</size><filedate>1308341221</filedate></file><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.0-rc1.zip</url><archive_type>zip</archive_type><md5>941111b41371084230bc82374ebcae19</md5><size>1682522</size><filedate>1308341221</filedate></file></files><terms><term><name>Release type</name><value>New features</value></term><term><name>Release type</name><value>Bug fixes</value></term></terms><security>RC releases are not covered by Drupal security advisories.</security></release><release><name>views 7.x-3.0-beta3</name><version>7.x-3.0-beta3</version><tag>7.x-3.0-beta3</tag><version_major>3</version_major><version_patch>0</version_patch><version_extra>beta3</version_extra><status>published</status><release_link>https://www.drupal.org/project/views/releases/7.x-3.0-beta3</release_link><download_link>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.0-beta3.tar.gz</download_link><date>1301301971</date><mdhash>114c76f201523ef3e50b9a1d431b0364</mdhash><filesize>1469580</filesize><files><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.0-beta3.tar.gz</url><archive_type>tar.gz</archive_type><md5>114c76f201523ef3e50b9a1d431b0364</md5><size>1469580</size><filedate>1301301971</filedate></file><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.0-beta3.zip</url><archive_type>zip</archive_type><md5>d69e051c8b4fa2066575c28e3ae197ba</md5><size>1671930</size><filedate>1301301971</filedate></file></files><terms><term><name>Release type</name><value>Bug fixes</value></term></terms><security>Beta releases are not covered by Drupal security advisories.</security></release><release><name>views 7.x-3.0-beta2</name><version>7.x-3.0-beta2</version><tag>7.x-3.0-beta2</tag><version_major>3</version_major><version_patch>0</version_patch><version_extra>beta2</version_extra><status>published</status><release_link>https://www.drupal.org/project/views/releases/7.x-3.0-beta2</release_link><download_link>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.0-beta2.tar.gz</download_link><date>1301158871</date><mdhash>c39fab1e76e55b15291fecf2c10386c2</mdhash><filesize>1469243</filesize><files><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.0-beta2.tar.gz</url><archive_type>tar.gz</archive_type><md5>c39fab1e76e55b15291fecf2c10386c2</md5><size>1469243</size><filedate>1301158871</filedate></file><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.0-beta2.zip</url><archive_type>zip</archive_type><md5>cd30442906e8d9e9bffc7ea8b28f3702</md5><size>1671405</size><filedate>1301158871</filedate></file></files><terms><term><name>Release type</name><value>Bug fixes</value></term></terms><security>Beta releases are not covered by Drupal security advisories.</security></release><release><name>views 7.x-3.0-beta1</name><version>7.x-3.0-beta1</version><tag>7.x-3.0-beta1</tag><version_major>3</version_major><version_patch>0</version_patch><version_extra>beta1</version_extra><status>published</status><release_link>https://www.drupal.org/project/views/releases/7.x-3.0-beta1</release_link><download_link>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.0-beta1.tar.gz</download_link><date>1301099796</date><mdhash>6ee4495cbdf0a8d19bd214f57bef0bf4</mdhash><filesize>1468892</filesize><files><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.0-beta1.tar.gz</url><archive_type>tar.gz</archive_type><md5>6ee4495cbdf0a8d19bd214f57bef0bf4</md5><size>1468892</size><filedate>1301099796</filedate></file><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.0-beta1.zip</url><archive_type>zip</archive_type><md5>36acc8675052e2dcb0c933e1ac8eab1d</md5><size>1670997</size><filedate>1301099796</filedate></file></files><terms><term><name>Release type</name><value>New features</value></term><term><name>Release type</name><value>Bug fixes</value></term></terms><security>Beta releases are not covered by Drupal security advisories.</security></release><release><name>views 7.x-3.0-alpha1</name><version>7.x-3.0-alpha1</version><tag>7.x-3.0-alpha1</tag><version_major>3</version_major><version_patch>0</version_patch><version_extra>alpha1</version_extra><status>published</status><release_link>https://www.drupal.org/project/views/releases/7.x-3.0-alpha1</release_link><download_link>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.0-alpha1.tar.gz</download_link><date>1294276882</date><mdhash>8635e5b0c03fed4516abae25489a5a5c</mdhash><filesize>1561161</filesize><files><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.0-alpha1.tar.gz</url><archive_type>tar.gz</archive_type><md5>8635e5b0c03fed4516abae25489a5a5c</md5><size>1561161</size><filedate>1294276882</filedate></file><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.0-alpha1.zip</url><archive_type>zip</archive_type><md5>f5ffc235849f2a3a5f66b66f84a73aac</md5><size>1772425</size><filedate>1294276882</filedate></file></files><terms><term><name>Release type</name><value>Bug fixes</value></term></terms><security>Alpha releases are not covered by Drupal security advisories.</security></release><release><name>views 7.x-3.x-dev</name><version>7.x-3.x-dev</version><tag>7.x-3.x</tag><version_major>3</version_major><version_extra>dev</version_extra><status>published</status><release_link>https://www.drupal.org/project/views/releases/7.x-3.x-dev</release_link><download_link>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.x-dev.tar.gz</download_link><date>1491154383</date><mdhash>b8b158ae6a7c9f4e84540fbfcfa83ee3</mdhash><filesize>1643061</filesize><files><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.x-dev.tar.gz</url><archive_type>tar.gz</archive_type><md5>b8b158ae6a7c9f4e84540fbfcfa83ee3</md5><size>1643061</size><filedate>1491154383</filedate></file><file><url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.x-dev.zip</url><archive_type>zip</archive_type><md5>db78a5499cda151d5a352a908adf7e6b</md5><size>1913538</size><filedate>1491154383</filedate></file></files><security>Dev releases are not covered by Drupal security advisories.</security></release></releases>
</project>
```

In short:

- You need to change the project update URL reported in the .info file of the module (e.g. http://domain.com)
- The server, on [http://domain.com/release-history/{project_name}/{drupal_version}](http://domain.com/release-history/%7Bproject_name%7D/%7Bdrupal_version%7D), needs to return XML data that describe all the project versions available and compatible with the Drupal version reported as last part of the URL (for example 7.x for Drupal 7, 8.x for Drupal 8)